# colorbox and preventdefault not working together?

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

I'm calling a colorbox using jquery and trying to prevent the address from changing but it seems to trigger an address change every time.  Here is my current code:

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='send_alert_div' class="wysiwyg_container">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        ....
    </div>
</div>

<a class="contact" href="#" >Contact</a>
```

my javascript code to handle the click event for Contact

```
$(".contact").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contact").colorbox({width:"600px", height: "420px", inline:true, href:"#send_alert_div"});
});
```

Does anyone see why this wouldn't work? It triggers an address change every time it's clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are talking about with address changes.  That must be controlled by some piece of script that you haven't included.  Furthermore, colorbox already applies e.preventDefault();  So you could simplify the above code to simply this:

```
$(".contact").colorbox({width:"600px", height: "420px", inline:true, href:"#send_alert_div"});
```

Your other issue sounds unrelated.  It's going to be difficult to instruct you on what to do without seeing what code is causing your 'address change', but if it is a simple event binding, you may be able to prevent it by replacing your above code with the following:

```
$(".contact").unbind('click').colorbox({width:"600px", height: "420px", inline:true, href:"#send_alert_div"});
```

Comment: I'm using the jquery address plugin so this is picking up my address change for some reason.  I tried the unbind but it didn't make a difference.  I'll take another look at the code and see if I'm missing something.

Comment: I ended up changing my href elements to span and everything is working great. Thanks!