# “owl carousel” and “colorbox” slide action issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, owl-carousel, unbind

I would need help concerning a slideshow problem with colorbox and owlcarrousel

I made the pictures in the “colorbox” module window slide many times.
After doing that and closing the module window, if I try to check the pictures I can see it became different and only one half of the pictures is displayed.
To make it easier to understand, I uploaded a movie of the problem on YouTube.

YouTube : https://youtu.be/uCOkgeoPSh8

Store : http://www.ks-clothing.click/men/tees-knits-and-polos/lexington-cardigan-sweater-479.html

Also, I followed the advice in the link below, I put “unbind” in the script, but it did not move.
How could I fix this problem?

stackoverflow : [colorbox and preventdefault not working together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577411/colorbox-and-preventdefault-not-working-together)

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>

<div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
            <div class="item">
                <a class="gallery" href="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>">Colorbox</a>
<!--                <a class="cloud-zoom" rel="position: 'inside' , showTitle: false" href="--><?php //echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?><!--">-->
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getGalleryImageUrl($_image); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
<!--                </a>-->
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("a.gallery").unbind('click').colorbox({
            rel:'slideshow',
            transition:'none',
            maxWidth:'100%',
            maxHeight:"100%",
            opacity: 0.5
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function($) {

            var sync1 = jQuery("#sync1");
            var sync2 = jQuery("#sync2");

            sync1.owlCarousel({
                singleItem : true,
                slideSpeed : 1000,
                navigation: true,
                pagination:false,
                afterAction : syncPosition,
                responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
            });

            sync2.owlCarousel({
                items : 15,
                itemsDesktop      : [1199,10],
                itemsDesktopSmall     : [979,10],
                itemsTablet       : [768,8],
                itemsMobile       : [479,4],
                pagination:false,
                responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
                afterInit : function(el){
                    el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
                }
            });

            function syncPosition(el){
                var current = this.currentItem;
                jQuery("#sync2")
                    .find(".owl-item")
                    .removeClass("synced")
                    .eq(current)
                    .addClass("synced")
                if(jQuery("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
                    center(current)
                }
            }

            jQuery("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var number = jQuery(this).data("owlItem");
                sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
            });

            function center(number){
                var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
                var num = number;
                var found = false;
                for(var i in sync2visible){
                    if(num === sync2visible[i]){
                        var found = true;
                    }
                }

                if(found===false){
                    if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
                        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
                    }else{
                        if(num - 1 === -1){
                            num = 0;
                        }
                        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
                    }
                } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
                    sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
                } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
                    sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
                }

            }
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `returnFocus: false` to colorbox options like so:

```
$("a.gallery").unbind('click').colorbox({
            rel:'slideshow',
            transition:'none',
            maxWidth:'100%',
            maxHeight:"100%",
            opacity: 0.5,
            returnFocus: false
        });
```

The focus return somehow confuses the Owl slider, which is indeed unexpected.